# SML can't use foldr to reverse a list

Tags: sml

I am trying to use `foldr` to reverse a list like the following

```
 fun revl2 x = foldr(fn(x,y)=>y@[x],[]);
```

and try this

```
 fun  revl1 x = foldr (op @) []x;
```

and this

```
 fun  revl1 x = foldr (op ::) []x;
```

it isn't work,I don't know why.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`foldr` is what we call a curried function. This means that instead of taking its arguments as a tuple, it takes one argument and then returns another curried function that takes the remaining arguments in the same way. In this case all that means is that you need to call it as `foldr f init list`, not `foldr (f, init, list)`.

So that's why your first attempt was wrong (that and the fact that you didn't supply the list argument at all). In your second and third attempt you did use the correct syntax to call it, but you no longer supplied the correct function.

The function given to `foldr` takes two arguments: an element of the list and the current value of the accumulator. In your case the accumulator is a list, so you need to supply a function where the first argument is an element of the list and the second is a list. In your second attempt you supplied `op @`, which takes two lists, so that does not work.

In your third attempt you supplied `op ::`, which does take an element and a list, but it adds the element at the beginning of the list. Since the result of `foldr (op ?) init xs` is `x1 ? x2 ? x3 ? ... ? xn ?? init`, you get `x1 :: x2 :: x3 :: ... :: xn :: []` in this case, which is simply the original list - nothing has been reversed.

So to solve the problem, you need to supply a function that adds a single element at the end of a list. That's exactly what the function in your first attempt did, so just use that one.

Answer (score 0):

[`foldr`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.foldr:VAL) has the signature `('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b` and is invoked as:

> foldr f init [x1, x2, ..., xn]
>       returns
>
> ```
> f(x1, f(x2, ..., f(xn, init)...))
>
> or init if the list is empty.
> ```

Note that `f` must be a function that accepts two arguments. Since the end result of your function is a list, then both elements must be lists.

To reverse a list with `foldr`:

```
 List.foldr (fn(x,y) => y @ [x]) [] [1,2,3]
```

Placing `[]` around the argument `x` creates the necessary list.

Comment: "Note that f must be a function that accepts two arguments of the same type." That's not true at all. The first argument has type 'a and the second has type 'b. Those do not have to be the same type. And in fact they aren't here. If x had the same type as y, they'd both be lists and you wouldn't have to add brackets around x. Also note that you didn't change the function from the OP's attempt at all - he already had that part right.

Comment: thank you,but I have one question to ask you. What is List.folder?

Comment: `List.foldr` is a fully qualified name of `foldr` from the SML Basis Library [ linked in my answer ]. The fully qualified name is more likely to work in a wider range of specific SML installations, so I type it out of habit.